# 'Tenure' vs. 'tenancy'

Tags: meaning

Can anyone clarify for me the differences between these two words, in their senses of "occupation by a tenant"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Tenure*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/tenure) is the legal right to live in a house or use a piece of land. [*Tenancy*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tenancy) is more like the occupation of a rented house. *Tenure* does not mean occupation by a tenant. So *tenure* is a right to *tenancy*; they are not the same, therefore they are not necessarily interchangeable; unless you are going off of the definition of *tenancy* meaning *[the right to live or work in a building that you rent](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/tenancy)*. However, since you wanted them in the sense "occupation by a tenant," they are not the same.